# Filter in restorted DynamicViewPanel resets sort

Tags: xpages

I have dynamic view control that is used to display several views from a database. I allow users to filter this view using input that is bound to a viewscope variable that is used in keys attribute of Domino View.

It works just fine, but some views have sortable column that strangely. Problem is that when users resorts the view and then tries to filter, the sort order is lost.

I also tried call setKeys programmatically on datasource, but with same results. Also setting setResortOrder on the dataModel has no effect. Sort order seems to be lost when different key value is set.

To get correct result, users have to resort the view again after submitting the sort.

(on Domino 9.0.1 with v11 ExtLib)

**update** - code snippet for basic scenario

```
<xp:panel id="content">
    <xp:inputText id="searchInput" value="#{viewScope.tmpSearchText}" />
    <xp:button id="search">
        Search
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="content">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.searchText=viewScope.tmpSearchText;}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xe:dynamicViewPanel id="viewPanel">
        <xe:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" keys="#{viewScope.searchText}"
                viewName="DleCislaW" >
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xe:this.data>
    </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Could you post a little of your code?

Comment: The code is pretty standard. If I try to add more, it doesn't help.